# Can't login with Google on recently released iPhones and iPads

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, login

I just switched from an iPhone 7 to an iPhone XR (both are on latest iOS version available).

When I try to login into the Stack Exchange app with my Google account it says:

> **Request failed**
>   Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging
>   back in. If this persist, let us know on meta.

this happens consistently.

I have 2FA enabled on my Google account if it matters.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Try using an application-specific password.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to login with an app-specific password, but in any case the login worked just fine on my iPhone 7...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: I was loggedin on my iPhone X, then I migrated to the iPhone Xs Max... On my iPhone xSMax I had to login via google again. I can pick my google account but afterwads I get the same error.

Comment: Same problem with an iPad. Switched from iPad Air to an iPad Pro and the login with Google fails.

Comment: No action after 20 days. This is very bad.

Comment: The app is not dead it's just a matter of interface authentication. It's useful for getting quick answers.

Comment: @egq not a single bug in the apps was fixed for several years.

Comment: @DorBar so how you call an app where its developers not fixing any of its bug, ever? I call it dead.

Comment: Yeah, last update was a year ago. It's dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed a while back.

There was a regression in Google's tokeninfo endpoint that was causing requests to fail server-side.  More details at [Unable to log in with Google account to the Stack Overflow iOS app (Request failed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372621/unable-to-log-in-with-google-account-to-the-stack-overflow-ios-app-request-fail/377269#377269)

Answer (score -1):

If SE will ever decide to assign a programmer to fix this bug, my advice is to start here: [403 Error - Thats an error. Error: disallowed_useragent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591090/403-error-thats-an-error-error-disallowed-useragent)

:)